# Running test from different modules using a testng suite in maven multi module project?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testng, multi-module

I want to run unit test present in different modules of my maven project from a testng suite that contains specific test classes.
One method that i have tried is to make another module and add dependencies of the different modules that i require test from as a test-jar but this method requires me to add all the dependencies that the modules i have added for test dependencies.

project is structure like

```
Project 
|
|- Module A
   |- src
   |- suitefiles
   |- pom.xml
|- Module B
   |- src
   |- suitefiles
   |- pom.xml
|-pom.xml(Parent pom)
```

I have tried to add a third module like

```
Project 
|
|- Module A
   |- src
   |- suitefiles
   |- pom.xml
|- Module B
   |- src
   |- suitefiles
   |- pom.xml
|- Module C
   |- src
   |- suitefiles
   |- pom.xml <-(A and B as dependencies here)
|-pom.xml(Parent pom)
```

I want to omit making a separate module every time to run combine test from 2 modules. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Please make an example project and show what you have tried so far..and what does not work...

Answer (score 0):

This should run tests for modules A and B both.

```
mvn test -pl A,B
```

---

**References**
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules-4.html
https://blog.akquinet.de/2010/05/26/mastering-the-maven-command-line-reactor-options/
https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/

Comment: I am trying to run test from a testng suite file that has some test classes from different modules( A and B)

Comment: If you like to run a single testng xml and reffer tests from different modules, you should add your test-jar dependencies to the new module. You always run tests for some module, the module should have the classes in classpath, so it should have the valid dependencies. The way for not creating a new module for test is just to run each module tests per it's own module. You'll have the results output in each module target directory. You might create a module with all other modules test-jars, for do this job as you like. But it's not possible without adding a new module.